# Entity Framework save big image

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am creating a field :

```
public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

This will create a fields called Image with data type `varbinary` and length is `4000`.

When I save a record, it will fail to save because the image is hugh to save in varbinary(4000).

How do I make it to image datattype or bigger binary length?

I am using sqlserver ce 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the mapping for your property to use `image` type in the database. You can do that either with data annotations:

```
[Column(TypeName = "image")]
public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

or with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<...>().Property(e => e.Image).HasColumnType("image");
```

Comment: Error: The type or namespace name 'ColumnAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema